# React select onChange not called when options change

Tags: reactjs, html-select

I have a `<select>` in my component where the list of options is filtered depending on state and is initialized with nothing.

```
render() {
  <select value={this.state.time} className='input' onChange={e => this.setState({time: e.target.value})} disabled={!this.state.date} >
    { availableDates.filter(d => moment(d).format('YYYY-MM-DD') === this.state.date).map(d =>
       <option key={d} value={moment(d).format('H:mm')}>{moment(d).format('H:mm')}</option>
    )}
</select>
}
```

It means that as long as `this.state.date` is `null`, the `select` has no `option`. Then when `date` is set, there is most of the time only one value. On the display, it becomes immediately selected.

But `onChange` is not triggered, and never is (even if I explicitly select the value).

Is this the expected behavior? Somehow, I'd say the value *changed* so the  `onChange` should be triggered, shouldn't it?

Besides, how can I make it work anyway? I need the select to be displayed even without options ...

Comment: How did you make sure `onChange` was not triggered? Maybe `e.target.value` is not what you expect. I generally save `e.target.value` in a `const` before calling the asynchronous `setState`.

Comment: @RaphaMex I don't think it's the issue in this case, but I agree it's important to know how to work with React's [Synthetic Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

Comment: I did use a `console.log` there but that said I'm not sure I understand what you meant: assigning `e.target.value` in a `const` won't make a difference, will it? Even if the `event` becomes nullified, `e.target.value` is a string so its content is static, not a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the state value was changed, but the select's change event, in fact, wasn't, it just got re-rendered with the new value.

Also, most browsers don't trigger the change event when re-selecting the current value (but if I recall it correctly, some old IEs do).

Hence, I believe that it's the expected behavior.

To make it work, in the code that sets the date state, it could also set the default time value. That makes sense, because you want to set the time when the date has changed.

As a side note, depending on how you'll implement that, you may want to take a look into [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but this brought me ugly code where I found the former solution quite elegant! A side-note though: even if the DOM doesn't trigger the event, React could have IMHO. The DOM is not much dynamic, so doesn't really *expect* the list of `<option>` to change, while that's pretty much why React exists. :-) Hence behaviors could be different. I reckon there are other examples where React doesn't mimic the DOM's event, though I can't remember one right now.